Random numbers are different in papers and answer keys - examdesign package
I am generating random numbers using the examdesign package, but the random numbers appear differently in the exam paper and the answer key. How can I generate the same random numbers in both the exam paper and the answer key?
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}


\newcount\stud
\include{random}

\newcount\ioffa
\newcount\eoffa

\stud=1
\rand=\stud

%\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\ConstantBlanks{2cm}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
%\ShortKey

\def\namedata{Name: \hrulefill \\
No: \hrulefill \\
Date: \hrulefill}

\SectionPrefix{\textbf{Section  \Roman{sectionindex}.} \space}

\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{}
\NumberOfVersions{4}

\class{{\Large University}\\ Department\\
Course Name}
\examname{Exam}

\begin{document}


\begin{fillin}[title={Fill in the blanks. (5pts each)}]
\begin{question}

\random\ioffa {30} {60}
\random\eoffa {10} {29}
Nominal interest rate is $0.\the\ioffa $. Inflation rate is $0.\the\eoffa $ effective rate? \blank{$1-\frac{(1+0.\the\ioffa)}{(1+0.\the\eoffa)}$}
\end{question}
\end{fillin}
\end{document}


Random number creation procedure is derived from Dr Amit K Awasthi in the answer following link
the code is as follows:
%Time = \the\time \par

\newcount\rand
\newcount\randa
\rand=\stud

% The following needed for pseudo-random algorithm
\newcount\den % denominator
\newcount\sub % whole part to be subtracted
\newcount\res % result

\newcount\ctwo
\newcount\cthree
\newcount\cfour
\newcount\cfive
\newcount\csix
\newcount\pom
\newcount\forneg
\newcount\forsumpr

\def\random#1#2#3{%
\global\multiply \rand by 121
\randa=\rand
\divide \randa by 1237
\multiply \randa by 1237
\global\advance \rand by -\randa % a pseudo-random number from 0 to 1236
\den=#3
\advance \den by -#2
\advance \den by 1     % now \den=#3-#2+1 = number of integers between #2 and #3 inclusive
\res=\rand
\sub=\rand
\divide \sub by \den
\multiply \sub by \den
\advance\res by -\sub % now \res = remainder of dividing \rand over \den
\advance\res by #2
#1=\res
}


\def\randomtwo#1#2{%
\random \ctwo 1 2
\ifnum \ctwo=1 #1 \ #2 \else #2 \ #1 \fi
}

\def\randomthree#1#2#3{%
\random \cthree 1 3
\ifnum \cthree=1 #1 \randomtwo{#2}{#3} \fi
\ifnum \cthree=2 #2 \randomtwo{#1}{#3} \fi
\ifnum \cthree=3 #3 \randomtwo{#1}{#2} \fi
}

\def\randomfour#1#2#3#4{%
\random \cfour 1 4
\ifnum \cfour=1 #1 \randomthree{#2}{#3}{#4} \fi
\ifnum \cfour=2 #2 \randomthree{#1}{#3}{#4} \fi
\ifnum \cfour=3 #3 \randomthree{#1}{#2}{#4} \fi
\ifnum \cfour=4 #4 \randomthree{#1}{#2}{#3} \fi
}

\def\randomfive#1#2#3#4#5{%
\random \cfive 1 5
\ifnum \cfive=1 #1 \randomfour{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5} \fi
\ifnum \cfive=2 #2 \randomfour{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5} \fi
\ifnum \cfive=3 #3 \randomfour{#1}{#2}{#4}{#5} \fi
\ifnum \cfive=4 #4 \randomfour{#1}{#2}{#3}{#5} \fi
\ifnum \cfive=5 #5 \randomfour{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4} \fi
}

\def\randomsix#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
\random \csix 1 6
\ifnum \csix=1 #1 \randomfive{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6} \fi
\ifnum \csix=2 #2 \randomfive{#1}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6} \fi
\ifnum \csix=3 #3 \randomfive{#1}{#2}{#4}{#5}{#6} \fi
\ifnum \csix=4 #4 \randomfive{#1}{#2}{#3}{#5}{#6} \fi
\ifnum \csix=5 #5 \randomfive{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#6} \fi
\ifnum \csix=6 #6 \randomfive{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5} \fi
}

\def\choosetwo#1#2#3{%
\random\ctwo 1 2
\ifnum \ctwo=1 #1=#2 \else #1=#3 \fi
}

\def\choosethree#1#2#3#4{%
\random\cthree 1 3
\ifnum \cthree=1 #1=#2 \fi
\ifnum \cthree=2 #1=#3 \fi
\ifnum \cthree=3 #1=#4 \fi
}

\def\choosefour#1#2#3#4#5{%
\random\cfour 1 4
\ifnum \cfour=1 #1=#2 \fi
\ifnum \cfour=2 #1=#3 \fi
\ifnum \cfour=3 #1=#4 \fi
\ifnum \cfour=4 #1=#5 \fi
}

\def\choosefive#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
\random\cfive 1 5
\ifnum \cfive=1 #1=#2 \fi
\ifnum \cfive=2 #1=#3 \fi
\ifnum \cfive=3 #1=#4 \fi
\ifnum \cfive=4 #1=#5 \fi
\ifnum \cfive=5 #1=#6 \fi
}

\def\choosesix#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
\random\csix 1 6
\ifnum \csix=1 #1=#2 \fi
\ifnum \csix=2 #1=#3 \fi
\ifnum \csix=3 #1=#4 \fi
\ifnum \csix=4 #1=#5 \fi
\ifnum \csix=5 #1=#6 \fi
\ifnum \csix=6 #1=#7 \fi
}

\def\sign#1{%
\ifnum #1<0 \the#1 \else +\the#1 \fi
}

\def\choosepom{%
\random\ctwo 1 2
\ifnum \ctwo=1 \pom=1 \else \pom=-1 \fi
}

\def\randompom#1#2#3{%
\random #1{#2}{#3}
\choosepom
\multiply #1 by \pom
}

\def\sumprod#1#2#3#4#5{%    #1 = #2*#3 + #4*#5
#1=#2
\multiply #1 by #3
\forsumpr=#4
\multiply \forsumpr by #5
\advance #1 by \forsumpr
}


Don't use \include on plain TeX code packages. Use \input{random} instead of \include{random}. \include is meant for text portions of your document that can have a \clearpage in between (usually chapters or similar).

I wouldn't recommend this random random snippet (with all due respect to its author). I suggest you work instead with well-maintained packages on CTAN that implement the same algorithms. Or maybe switch to LuaTeX so that you can access its scripting layer. The main feature you need for predictability is the option of setting the random seed once per exam version.
But the main issue here is that examdesign typesets each question twice, once as the student form and once as the answer key, and you need the same “random” number on each consecutive pair of runs. Since the number of versions is limited to 26 anyway, it may be better to generate a parameter list externally and let each version choose its parameter from that list.
That's what I did with the randomlist package. I'm really only using it for its list features, not its randomization.
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{randomlist}

\ConstantBlanks{2cm}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering

\def\namedata{Name: \hrulefill \\
No: \hrulefill \\
Date: \hrulefill}

\SectionPrefix{\textbf{Section  \Roman{sectionindex}.} \space}

\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{}
\NumberOfVersions{4}

\class{{\Large University}\\ Department\\
Course Name}
\examname{Exam}

\NewList{ioffas}
\SetList{ioffas}{NULL,56,37,56,57,30,50,44,47,30,39}
\NewList{eoffas}
\SetList{eoffas}{NULL,13,10,29,29,25,19,13,26,21,26}
\begin{document}


\begin{fillin}[title={Fill in the blanks. (5pts each)}]
\begin{question}
\GetItem{ioffas}{\arabic{version}}{ioffa}
\GetItem{eoffas}{\arabic{version}}{eoffa}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myanswer}{(1 - (1+\ioffa*0.01)/(1+\eoffa*0.01)}
Nominal interest rate is $0.\ioffa$. Inflation rate is $0.\eoffa $ effective rate? \blank{$\myanswer$}
\end{question}
\end{fillin}
\end{document}

I used random.org to generate the parameter lists in the intervals you wanted. The examdesign class has a version counter, which loops from 1 up to the number you declare with \NumberOfVersions. The randomlist package indexes its lists from zero, which is why I put that NULL at the beginning of the list.
The \GetItem lines set the \ioffa and \eoffa commands to be the versionth item from the corresponding lists. The rest of the math is done with the pgfmath package.

Dear Matthew, thank you so much for your response. The code you wrote not only works perfectly but is also instructive. You saved me hours.

The source coude of random states that it uses \randomi as seed.
So I tried
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\input{random} % not \include, as suggested by Skillmon
\newcount\ioffa


\begin{document}
\global\randomi=12345  % Set the seed of the random function
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa

\global\randomi=12345  % Set the seed of the random function back to the original value
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\setrannum{\ioffa}{1}{100}
\the\ioffa
\end{document}

As you can see, it produces the same sequence twice.
Hence if you set the seed in both documents to the same value, it should give the corresponding answers to the questions

Thank you for your response. However, I don't know how to check the random numbers in the second file. The examdesign package generates the question paper and the answer key right after. I can't check the random numbers before the answer key is created. We could define the random numbers before \begin{document}, but this will generate the same random numbers for all versions. I want random numbers to be generated when the answer key for version A is created and used in A’s answer key, while different random numbers are generated for version B and used in B’s answer key.

The \global\randomi=12345 can be done before the \begin{document}. This means that you can put that statement into an extra file and input it. Then you can use a script that generates some number, writes the single line file that defines \randomi and creates both documents by invoking your TeX interpreter. On the next run the script generates a new number and you'll end up with a next version of the documents.
